# Question about PHP function return

Tags: php, function, return

I want to check if any of the three functions inside the IF did not execute successfully. If any of them did not run, i want to get a return value false.

```
if($ext == "gif" or $ext == "png"){
    imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127));
    imagealphablending($new, false);
    imagesavealpha($new, true);
    }
```

For example I want to know if all the three functions imagecolortransparent, imagealphablending, imagesavealpha did execute successfully, if not, return false. 
    Do i need to check each function like following or is there **a better way**?

```
if($ext == "gif" or $ext == "png"){
    if (!@imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127)))
        return false;
    if (!@imagealphablending($new, false))
        return false;
    if (!@imagesavealpha($new, true))
        return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: i was just wondering if i need to return the false for each of the function, because in my image resize function im using many built in image related functions, so i have to return each of the function return value individually.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if($ext == "gif" or $ext == "png"){
if ((!@imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127)))
    || (!@imagealphablending($new, false))
    || (!@imagesavealpha($new, true)) )
   {
        return false;
   }

}
```

this will also do the same function. But in both the way you wont know which function failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can join them in 1 single if, but your method is probably the better way because it won't execute the following statements if one of the function calls fails.

Comment: The boolean `&&` operator will short-circuit as well, stopping execution when a `false` is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a custom error handler that translates all PHP errors into `ErrorException`s and register it globally. Once you've done that, an error in any of the three functions will raise an exception, which you can handle with a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!@imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127))
  || !@imagealphablending($new, false)
  || !@imagesavealpha($new, true)) return false;
```

or just

```
return (@imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127))
     && @imagealphablending($new, false)
     && @imagesavealpha($new, true));
```

Don't know, if the `@` is required here. You should try to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you do is quite okay, you can concatenate the expressions however. It's doing the same, and in case a function returns false, the expression will not be followed for the rest (runtime optimization):

```
if($ext == "gif" or $ext == "png"){
    if (
        @imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127))
        and @imagealphablending($new, false)
        and @imagesavealpha($new, true)
    ) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Or <strike>by using a variable and</strike> sparing the second if thus making it more expressive:

```
if($ext == "gif" or $ext == "png")
    return 
      @imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127))
      && @imagealphablending($new, false)
      && @imagesavealpha($new, true)
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I would do it.

```
if($ext == "gif" or $ext == "png"){
  $return = TRUE;
  $return = $return && imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127));
  $return = $return && imagealphablending($new, false);
  $return = $return && imagesavealpha($new, true);
  return $return;
}
```

Basically I am `And`-ing all the responses to verify that they are all true. If any one of them returns `FALSE`, the function will return `FALSE`.

There are more beautiful ways to do it, but I find this way to be reasonably clear exactly what is happening.

Comment: May I ask why the downvote? I'm always open to constructive criticism.